# How to add a project as a library in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, project

How can I add a project like (RootTools) on another project as library in Android Studio?

I am using Android Studio 0.8.1 and I don't know how to add another project (folder) and I found a lot of information about importing jar files, but this is not the case.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the project as a git repository?

Comment: No, I have on a local folder, one is my project, generated by Android Studio, and the other is a project downloaded from a github repo: https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools

Comment: Goto File>>Project Structure>>Select Modules in left panel and click your main project now goto dependencies tab and click plus icon on right side and choose module dependencies add your library project from list after this you can see your library project in dependencies list now check checkbox from left side and apply.

Comment: I have imported the project, but in my project, when I go to Select Modules, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to import your library manually rather than using "Import Module" since it 1) will change directory layout for the library; 2) you can catch bugs (as I did) because Android Studio is still in beta.

To accomplish this:

1) Copy your library folder under /libraries

**2) Create build.gradle file inside library folder you've just copied, with similar content:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

3) Add `include ':libraries:RootTools'` to your `settings.gradle`

4) Add dependency to the `build.gradle` under the **app** module:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:RootTools')
    ...
}
```

5) Run `./gradlew assembleDebug` to assemble your project, including the library.

Comment: When I do all those steps the gradle build fails at several points in the Manifest file. Every time I am referencing a source or resource of the library project, a "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'x' with value '@string/x_x')." occurs. Searching for a solution since ages...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it manual, you can follow the steps below.

1. Create a folder as called "libraries" in top level. Not necessary but it will help you to have a good structure when you need to add more libraries.
2. Copy the project folder under libraries.
3. open **settings.gradle** and add the project.

> include ':libraries:RootTools'

1. Open **build.gradle** of the your project, not the top level build.gradle and add dependency

> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.+'
>     compile project(':libraries:RootTools')
> }
> ```

then `run` or .`/gradlew assemble`

```
app 
- build.gradle //  add dependency
libraries
- RootTools
settings.gradle // add project
```

Comment: Error:(24, 0) Project with path ':libs:RootTools' could not be found in project ':app'. I don't know why?

Comment: where is your libs folder? make sure you added it to same level as settings.gradle

Comment: inside, app->libs->"RootTools"

Comment: no no. create another folder outside of app, that's why I make the name "libraries" instead of libs. app has libs folder for jars to put, this one is for projects and create the folder in the same level as app folder, It shouldn't be under app

Comment: I went to upload a screenshot, but I will try to put firstly in the same level as settings.gradle as you had said. Thanks.

Comment: I have 2 build.gradle. One inside app folder, and one in the high level, the same as settings.gradle. In which of those files I have to put compile project(':libraries:RootTools')?

Comment: Done. Now, I'm getting this error --> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56892/discussion-between-nr4bt-and-victor-j-martin).